# Ubuntu 20 LTS proper way to permanently change tc qdisc for a network interface?

Tags: networking, server

Is there an existing proper way to define tc qdisc settings (or tc settings in general, need some filters too) for a network interface at boot or do I have to write my own systemd startup script?

I'm aware of sysctl net.core.default_qdisc and have changed it to plain prio as default, but the main internet facing interface needs a more detailed setup.

Since I'm much of an Ubuntu and systemd newbie I wouldn't mind if someone shared a systemd script template to run at boot, if there's no other way.

Edit: Didn't know about crontab @reboot , might be the easiest way to this.

Comment: Since you said LTS I assume you mean 20.04?

Comment: Yes that would be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So creating a oneshot systemd startup script really was the easiest and most useful answer:

```
# ls -l local-startup.service
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 378 Feb 23  2021 local-startup.service
# cat /etc/systemd/system/local-startup.service
[Unit]
Description=Run once at startup to inizialize things
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
StandardOutput=append:/tmp/local-startup.service.out
StandardError=inherit
ExecStart=-/bin/bash -x /etc/local/local-startup.service.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the actual startup script in the specified location, the qdisc change script is source'd from the script:

```
# ls -l /etc/local/local-startup.service.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1512 Nov 13  2021 /etc/local/local-startup.service.sh
# cat /etc/local/local-startup.service.sh
#!/bin/bash
source /what/ever/somewhere/script.sh
# any other local startup commands in the following lines
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `netplan` for configuring the network then there is no way to set qdiscs directly, so you'll probably find it easier to install `networkd-dispatcher` and put your commands in `routable.d/` or `configured.d/`.

[The upstream site](https://gitlab.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher) has more info on usage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just wondering is it really easier than manually creating a oneshot systemd script.